# Java: how to run jar application as MS Windows Context Menu (Right Click on Screen)?

Tags: java, jar, contextmenu, regedit

I read this [article](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=168&t=Copy_File_Path_And_Name_Using_Windows_Explorer_Context_Menu_Extensions) and wanted to do same thing using Java (.jar) file instead of .exe

And suppose my program just prints the path of the selected file which right clicked to my content menu.

Please see below Image. I want like this the **option(Copy File Path)** in MS Windows Context Menu using a Java Application:

[image]
Sorry for my weird language, i hope somebody fix that.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Open with then select java under JDK_HOME.
then you are free to run it after clicking...

Answer (score -2):

You only have to double-click on the .jar file.

Comment: wow! Best solution ever!

Comment: This is not what OP is asking. Check the article link he has put in question